# Dragging Sprite Array in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

My goal is to spawn a circle on the `MOUSE_WHEEL` event, and move *all* of them when a dragging occurs, as detected with `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP`. I've done this by adding each `Sprite` created into an array, and iterating through it when mouse up/down. Note: `Node` is just an extension of the `Sprite` type.

However, for some reason, only the most recently drawn `Sprite` in the array is being moved. Any ideas why?

My Canvas class:

```
    public function Canvas() {
        trace("Starting it");

        const background:Sprite = new Sprite();
        background.graphics.beginFill(0x00000000);
        background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
        background.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(background);

        background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, createNode);
        background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startObjectMove);
        background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endObjectMove);


        mNodeList = new Array();
    }
...
}
```

My startObjectMove and endObjectMove methods:

```
        public function startObjectMove(pEvent:MouseEvent) : void {
        trace("Starting drag...");
        trace("There are " + mNodeList.length + " in list");
        for (var i:int = 0; i < mNodeList.length; i++) {
            var node:Node;
            node = Node(mNodeList[i]);
            node.startMove(pEvent);
        }
    }
    public function endObjectMove(pEvent:MouseEvent) : void {
        trace("Ending drag...");
        trace("There are " + mNodeList.length + " in list");
        for (var i:int = 0; i < mNodeList.length; i++) {
            var node:Node;
            node = Node(mNodeList[i]);
            node.endMove(pEvent);
        }
    }
```

The `endMove` and `startMove` methods simply call `this.startDrag()` and `this.endDrag()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use startDrag and stopDrag on one object at a time.

You need to listen for mouse down events on the stage itself - when the user clicks, store the initial position of each node (create two public vars/properties in the Node class), and also record where the mouse starts out.

Then, whenever the mouse moves until it's released, work out how far it's moved since mouse down, and add this amount to the initial position of each node to set its position.

You need to do something like this:

```
var initX:int;//Variables to store the mouse position on click:
var initY:int;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN):void {

    initX = stage.mouseX;//Store the starting mouse position
    initY = stage.mouseY;


    //Store the node positions:
    for(var i:int = 0; i < mNodeList.length; i++){
        var node:Node = Node(mNodeList[i]);
        node.startX = node.x;
        node.startY = node.y;
    }

    //Listen for mouse move events
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMove);
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP):void {
    //Stop listening for mouse move events
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMove);
}



//MouseMove event handler:

function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void{
        for(var i:int = 0; i < mNodeList.length; i++){
                var node:Node = Node(mNodeList[i]);

                // Position each as amount the mouse has moved 
                // to each node's initial position:

                node.x = (stage.mouseX-initX) + node.startX;
                node.y = (stage.mouseY-initY) + node.startY;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, never knew you couldn't use that for multiple objects!

Comment: I hope it works, I've amended it quite a bit if you want to look again!